# Moongose: Insert Many Docs then get Id and Update another Doc in another Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of Users and Payments, and I need to add the Payments Id to their respective Users after they're created, but I don't find a eficient way of doing it.

```js
const users = [
  {
    documentId: '123456789',
    fullname: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    payments: []
  },
  {
    documentId: '987654321',
    fullname: 'Fred Flinstone',
    email: 'fred@gmail.com',
    payments: []
  },
  {
    documentId: '101010101',
    fullname: 'Mary Poppins',
    email: 'mary@gmail.com',
    payments: []
  }
]

const payments = [
  {
    billId: 1,
    concept: 'Groceries',
    amount: 10,
    amountWithSymbol: '10$',
    payHolder: 'John Doe'
  },
  {
    billId: 2,
    concept: 'Dinner',
    amount: 15,
    amountWithSymbol: '15$',
    payHolder: 'John Doe'
  }
  {
    billId: 3,
    concept: 'Meal',
    amount: 8,
    amountWithSymbol: '8$',
    payHolder: 'Fred Flinstone'
  }
]

/* 
  I need to insert each payment get their Id and then add it to a User document.
  This is the only way I found.
*/
payments.forEach(async pay => {
  const paymentRecorded = await paymentsModel.create(pay);
  const paymentUser = await usersModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { fullname: pay.payHolder },
    { payments: [paymentRecorded._id] }
  );
});
```

I know the way I do it, overwrites the previous recorded payments, so if you can solve that part too, I'd really appreciate it.